# FB.ui permissions.request does not work properly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

It became really annoying when discovered new bugs today.

Basicly what i'm trying to do is; showing a Facebook dialog box and getting needed permissions to app and run callback js function. But can not achieve this simple and the most important part of the app.

First, lets initialize it:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {

        FB.init({appId: '135814169854494', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

        FB.ui({method: "permissions.request", "perms": 'publish_stream,user_about_me,email,user_birthday,user_likes'} , function(response) { console.log(response); });

    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/<?=$__FBLocal?>/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

[image]

Now Javascript popup displays but if you click **Okay, Go to App** button, it does not grant permissions or even popup does not go away. Nothing changes! *weird*

If you disable **Enhanced Auth Dialog** from Advanced Application Settings in Facebook Developers section,

[image]

PopUp Style changes:

[image]

When you click Allow button, a javascript error throws: **FB.Auth.setSession incompatible with OAuth2.**

It is really common bug. There are some tips to not to get this bug i could find but all of them is not working. ( Such as; remove any extensions to all.js url -which i don't have- or change oauth parameter in FB.init -does not solve anything anymore- )

So , the only workaround is -unfortunately- embeding the permissions dialog in to page by redirecting. If someone can achieve JS SDK permission dialog , please let me know. Really stuck with lack of documentation in Graph API pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest creating another facebook application to get a new facebook ID and test with it.  If it works, then something was corrupt within facebook's storagea of the original facebook application's data.  If it doesn't work, then you have a reproducible bug which you can report to facebook via their bug tracking tool.

Comment: i tried it before, also having the problem with several apps.. :/

Comment: Then you have a reproducible situation that need to be reported to Facebook ASAP. :)  Please post a link to the bug report here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure permissions.request is deprecated.  Can you try using `method: oauth` instead of `permissions.request`?  Also, the `perms` param needs to change to `scope`.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: method: oauth is not working for Javascript dialog box. I converted to popup unfortunately. (FB.login)

Comment: According to this bug report, they are saying to use FB.login and not call permissions.request or the oauth dialog directly.  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273074112747891